# Insert data into specific row using MySQL in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, insert, sql-insert

I am trying to insert data in a specific row using MYSQL in PYTHON.

I've tried the following code :

```
sql = "INSERT INTO board (pages) VALUES (%s) WHERE (ASIN) = '" + asinList[x] + "'"
val = (a)
myCurser.execute(sql, val)
```

However, I got this error :

"

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s) WHERE
>   (ASIN) = 'B07KWSRMK1'' "

how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` does not support `WHERE` clause with `VALUES`.

If you really want add  a  new rows then  you should use `INSERT`.

```
 sql = "INSERT INTO board (pages) VALUES (%s) '"
```

You may be looking to update an existing row. In this you should use `UPDATE`:

```
sql = "UPDATE  board 
       SET pages = %s
       WHERE ASIN  = %s"
```